# java.lang.NullPointerException, when i am inside the constructor of a managed bean invoking methods from other beans

Tags: java, jsf, jakarta-ee, managed-bean

When I am inside the constructor of a managed and trying to reach out to other methods from other beans, I got `java.lang.NullPointerException`. Is there some kind of specification that not allow managed bean to do that?

```
@ManagedProperty(value="#{document}")
private DisplayListController document;

@EJB
DocumentSBean sBean;

public NewUserController() {
    document.list();
}
```

Above I just do regular bean injection, nothing fancy. `document` is a `SessionScoped` managed bean that has method `list()` which just return a `String`. `NewUserController` is a `RequestScoped` managed bean.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should look into [@PostConstruct.](http://lia.deis.unibo.it/Courses/TecnologieWeb0708/materiale/laboratorio/guide/j5eeapi/javax/annotation/PostConstruct.html)  An example can be found [here.](http://sqltech.cl/doc/oas10gR3/web.1013/b14428/ses30cfg.htm#CEGJIEJD)

Your properties are not being set when you're trying to access them.  You need to wait for them to be set.  Bean management typically goes:

1. Create Beans
2. Set Properties

You're trying to use properties that have not been set, thus resulting in your NPE.

So your code could change to:

```
public NewUserController() { }

@PostConstruct
public void init() {
    document.list();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

DisplayListController should probably be configured to call its own init method with the @PostConstruct annotation on the list method